# How do you answer the unanswerable questions?

Tags: apologetics

How do you respond to the "trivia" or "only God knows" type questions which cannot be answered from the Bible or science (yet)?  This is more of a general question, such as do you blow them off or provide a generic "Only God can truly know the answer to that, and I have faith that he does" type answer?

For example (you don't have to answer these ;) ):

- What was there before God created the universe?
- Can God make a rock He can't move?

Comment: I have to give credit to @El'endia Starman for asking the rock question and blowing my mind.

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? This sounds like a question better suited for meta. Maybe you need to reword or clarify.

Comment: @dleyva I agree. This either sounds like not a real question for Christianity.se or too many questions that are not related enough to fit in one question. Someone please fix it because it could be a good question but as it stands it isn't.

Comment: Ask a physicist what was there before the Big Bang... ;-)

Comment: @Steve Moser and dleyva this wasn't necessarily meant as a question of how to handle these on Christianity.se, but more general when they're asked in real life.  I'll try to put in more of my thought behind them.

Comment: I believe this belongs to META.C.SE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is meant by "God is Omnipotent"?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8242/what-is-meant-by-god-is-omnipotent)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My general response is to redirect the questioner to what their real issue is - most often, these questions are asked as a way of attacking fringe aspects of Christianity, and the real issue the questioner has is at his heart: he's not yet saved, and is scared that God's not happy with him, so to make himself feel better, he posts strawman and fringe-topic questions to make the Christian he is speaking with look like an idiot.

Answer (score 4):

Most of them contain logical fallacies, like the one you mentioned "Can God make a rock He can't move?" In other hand a valid "trivia" gives an opportunity to test your faith. Personally I wouldn't like to know that there is answer to any question. This give great meaning when I talk with other people, with honest motivation, about a topic which is not very clear with result to have great discussions and exchange of different opinions and views.